# How to make these SVG images align side by side without vanishing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I have some code that looks like this (using Bootstrap 4):

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
     <h1>Single and Satisfied</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg">
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I've also got a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/davidshq/pen/VwvrRGg

I'd like the result to look something like this:

`Single and Satisfied  Image1   Image2   Image3`

Instead I get something like this:

```
Single and Satisfied  Image1
                      Image2
                      Image3
```

If I use floats or `d-flex` in an attempt to get the images to appear on the same line the images disappear entirely.

From what I've read this has to do with the SVGs being responsive and sizing themselves to the parent, which is of no size by default. I'm thinking I can define a size on the parent container but trying to understand the best way to do this in a Bootstrap approved manner.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the size of svg are too big to render, so you can use `flex` and use the height and width property for the svg, it will take care of the rest, you can see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

> The svg is too big so I have given size fo `100px` each, using `flex` will take care of your requirement.

```css
.row,.align{
  display:flex; 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
     <h1>Single and Satisfied</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 align">
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" style="height:100px;width:100px;">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" style="height:100px;width:100px;">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
       <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" style="height:100px;width:100px;">
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `col-xs-4` as far as I see from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options, you could mean `col-4`.

Since you're trying to lay out three images in one line, you shall wrap them with `.row`:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/Kmq.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```